# Why is query router storing all of the data in mongodb cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to set up mongodb cluster, I have got 1 config server, 1 query router and 2 mongod instance. Here is my script to set up the cluster

```
mongod --configsvr --port 27010 --dbpath ~/mongodb/data1
mongos -configdb localhost:27010 --port 27011 
mongod --port 27012 --dbpath ~/mongodb/data2 
mongod --port 27013 --dbpath ~/mongodb/data3 

sh.addShard("localhost:27012")
sh.addShard("localhost:27013")

sh.enableSharding("tags")
db.tweets.ensureIndex( { _id : "hashed" } )
sh.shardCollection("tags.tweets", { "_id": "hashed" } )
```

In order to insert the data, I am using this script

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27011")
db=connection.tags
tweets = db.tweets


def main(jsonfile):
    f = open(jsonfile)

    for line in f.readlines():
        try:
            tweet_dict = json.loads(line)
            result = tweets.insert_one(tweet_dict)
            print result.inserted_id
        except  Exception as e:
            print "Unexpected error:", type(e), e
            sys.exit()
```

Why my tweets, which I am trying to insert, are getting sharded, all of the tweets I am trying to insert are also getting stored in query router. Is this behaviour expected?

The whole point of cluster is horizontal scalability(i.e. tweets getting split among machine), so for all of the tweets to accumulate in query router seems counter-intuitive?

Can anybody explain why it is happening? Why query router has all of the tweets I have inserted?

Comment: Why do you think your query router has all the tweets ? Apparently query router has no data storage on disk (like --dbpath of other mongo roles). So I don't know why do you conclude so.

Comment: Hmm. If I had seen this the day you posted then I would have said the same as well as put your question on hold ( as it should be, not least of which reasons being that it is a question for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. But Ho Hum, damage is already done! So you seem to be asking *"Why are writes not being distibuted to each shard?"*. Which is more to the point and using the correct terminology.

Comment: So here's the "rub" as they say. What is being inserted into `_id`? As the docs state, monotonic values are a good thing for hashed keys because they will ditstribute well. But if each new `_id` value is not actually an "increment" from the previous one, then hashed indexes are a big fail, and there is no guarantee where they are going to write, thus they can "hotspot". Understand? Communication with people is a lot more productive than setting a bounty.

Comment: This question is a non-sense, it's impossible. Mongos is stateless and doesn't store any data. With this testing cluster, the data will be stored evenly in the 2 mongod nodes regardless of the _id content because of the hashed shard key. Please consider reading MongoDB documentation, your knowledge of the MongoDB system seems light.

Answer (score 1):

You ask why your inserted tweets "are also getting stored in query router".  The short answer is that the only copy of each document is stored on one of the underlying shard servers, and nothing is stored on the query router.  The mongos process is not started with a --dbpath parameter, so it has nowhere to store data.

I set up an environment just like yours and then I then used a python script similar to yours to connect to the mongos (aka query router) and insert 200 documents to tags.tweets.  Now when I connect to the mongos and count the documents in tags.tweets, it finds 200.

```
$> mongo --port 27011 tags
mongos> db.tweets.count()
200
```

However, when I run getShardDistribution it shows `docs 91` on the first shard, and `docs 109` docs on the second:

```
mongos> db.tweets.getShardDistribution()

 Shard shard0000 at localhost:27301
  data : 18KiB docs : 91 chunks : 2
  estimated data per chunk : 9KiB
  estimated docs per chunk : 45

 Shard shard0001 at localhost:27302
  data : 22KiB docs : 109 chunks : 2
  estimated data per chunk : 11KiB
  estimated docs per chunk : 54

 Totals
  data : 41KiB docs : 200 chunks : 4
  Shard shard0000 contains 45.41% data, 45.5% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 210B
  Shard shard0001 contains 54.58% data, 54.5% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 211B
```

How the query router works is it passes all commands to the underlying shard servers and then combines their responses before returning a result the to the caller.  The count() of 200 returned above was just the sum of a count() done on each shard.

There's a lot more information about using MongoDB sharding for horizontal scalability in the sharding documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding).  You might find the [section on metadata](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-metadata/) helpful for your current issue.